# Installing Hyper-V for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v

I need to get Hyper-V so I can get Drupal and Lando working on my PC.
I went to the Microsoft download for remote server tools and downloaded  the 64 bit download.
When I try to install it the installer opens and then sits on Initilizing Installation forever.

I have Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question it sounds like you are asking if you can install Hyper-V on Windows 7 Pro x64. The answer is no. Hyper-V is supported only on Windows 8 and newer and on Windows Server 2008 and newer. Remote Server Admin Tools are designed for connecting to a remote Hyper-V server. In the case of Windows 7 you will only be able to connect to Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64. If this is the case please let me know and I will be happy to revise my answer.

I would suggest VirtualBox as an alternative. It is free and supports pretty much any guest OS / application. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Hyper-V Tools will not do what Lando is requiring? I got Hyper-V Tools on but now I can't install Lando because it says Hyper-V isn't there.

Comment: Right. You have installed the Hyper-V management tools NOT Hyper-V itself. Like stated in my answer Hyper-V will not run on Windows 7 Pro.  I updated my answer I would suggest installing VirtualBox you other option is of course updating to Windows 10 but that has additional system requirements and may not be best in your situation.

Comment: I'm currently putting Ubuntu onto a USB. Would you recommend a software like Virtual box over this? Considering I'm going to be using this for Drupal development.

Comment: I can not speak to Drupal as I have never used it. I am assuming Drupal runs on top of an OS. Based on you originally wanting Hyper-V. VirtualBox will run on Windows 7 Pro no problem. It runs on pretty much any OS (with a GUI) and supports pretty much any OS. That is the beauty of it. You do not need Ubuntu specifically for VirtualBox if that is what you are thinking.